# I am trying to call a 3rd party api and it is giving me a CORS error

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, serverless

```
const https = require('https');

export async function main(event, callback) {
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        host: 'https://api.challonge.com/v1/',
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
            "api_key": "THE_KEY",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
        }
    };
    var dataString = " ";

    const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = https.get(options, function (response) {
            response.on('data', chunk => {
                dataString += chunk;
            });
            response.on('end', () => {
                resolve({
                    statusCode: 200,
                    headers: {
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify((dataString))
                });
            });
        });
        req.on('error', (e) => {
            reject({
                statusCode: 500,
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                },
                body: e.message
            });
        });
    });
    return response;
};
```

This is the lambda function ^

```
getChallongeTournaments:
    handler: getChallongeTournaments.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: tournaments/
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
```

my serverless.yml

```
// in a useEffect
function getChallongeTournaments(){
     return API.get("byoc_users", '/tournaments.json');
    }
    async function onLoaded() {
      try {
       const testChallonge = await getChallongeTournaments();
```

^ The API call

According to the challonge docs this should receive 'Retrieve a set of tournaments created with your account.' and there is one created.

This is the CORS error I'm receiving: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://m3heucf413.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/prod/tournaments.json' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: Access-control-allow-credentials probably doesn't do what you think it does, and imposes strange rules. The most common error is that lambda blowups return 500 without cors from API gateway service

Answer (score 0):

Preflight Requests and CORS flag is raised by the Browser when there is a request from a domain/port to an entire new domain/port. If you are doing this for testing, you can disable this security flag in chrome by adding the `--disable-web-security` flag. Just create a shortcut of chrome to desktop > Right click > Properties >In shortcut tab - Target > Append `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\tmpChromeSession"` to target. This will disable the CORS check.

If you have access/control on the 3rd party api server config, what you should be doing is to add necessary response headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) to the response. If you do not have access, one option will be to route the request through a CORS proxy.